# select query not performing strict search when using join

Tags: mysql

I have a custom field for my post form. all things work perfectly but on search result page when I want to search with a custom field there is some issue in 'AND oprater '.
I don't understand why my query gives 0 results.

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM `ad_product` AS p
        JOIN `ad_custom_data` AS c ON c.product_id = p.id
WHERE STATUS = 'active'
        AND ((c.field_id = '1'
                AND CASE
                    WHEN (c.field_type = 'text-field')
                    THEN c.field_data LIKE '%BMW%'
                    ELSE c.field_data = 'BMW'
                END
            )
            AND (c.field_id = '7'
                AND CASE
                    WHEN (c.field_type = 'text-field')
                    THEN c.field_data LIKE '%3%'
                    ELSE c.field_data = '3'
                END
            )
        )
```

Can someone please help explain why my query is not correct?

Custom_data Table structure

```
id product_id field_id field_type    field_data
 1     1           1   text-field      BMW
 2     1           2   radio-buttons     3
 3     2           1   text-field      Audi
 4     2           2   radio-buttons     3
```

I want strict search

Example: user search in
text field = BMW and radio checked value = 3
Then i want only product_id = 1 row to be select.

But in this query, I am getting both product_id 1,2 this is the error

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what this does, but I think, you need an `OR` instead of an `AND` between the two complex condition starting with `c.field_id = [...]`.

So something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM `ad_product` AS p
        JOIN `ad_custom_data` AS c ON c.product_id = p.id
WHERE STATUS = 'active' 
        AND p.category = '1'
        AND p.country = 'IN'
        AND ((c.field_id = '1'
                AND CASE
                    WHEN (c.field_type = 'text-field' OR c.field_type = 'textarea')
                    THEN c.field_data LIKE '%Maruti%'
                    ELSE c.field_data = 'Maruti'
                END
            )
            OR (c.field_id = '7'
                AND CASE
                    WHEN (c.field_type = 'text-field' OR c.field_type = 'textarea')
                    THEN c.field_data LIKE '%3%'
                    ELSE c.field_data = '3'
                END
            )
        )
```

Comment: Yes i know when i do it with or this gives me result but i want strict search result. 

this is my site .

https://bylancer.com/products/classified-php-script/category/1/cars-bikes

issue in advance search not gives strict search result. I used 'OR' as you said

Comment: I got that, but if you set it to `AND`, then you basically tell it to get the records, where the `field_id` column in the `ad_custom_data` table equals to 1, and also equals to 7. Can you see the problem with that? Also, can you provide a sample dataset, and a desired result set? That way it would be much easier.

Comment: @ÐevendraKatariya Edit your question, not my answer, please. :)

Comment: Just added the table structure of custom_data. Can you create sql for me what i have to do for custom data search.

Comment: Can you describe with your own words, what do you want to achieve with this query? What are your input variables? What do you want to get as a result set?